# Non dimensionalization

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dimensional-analysis

How did he find the second derivative of $\theta$ with respect to $t$ ?
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2 \theta}{\mathrm d t^2} = \omega^2  \frac{\mathrm d^2 \theta }{\mathrm d \tau^2}$$

$\tau = \omega  t$
The first derivative $\tau'= \omega$, however the second derivative, $\omega$ is a constant independent of $t$. So the second derivative should be $0$ shouldnt it?

[Non dimensionalization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1abp.png)

Comment: Of course $d^2 \tau/dt^2 = 0$, but the computation is about finding $d^2 \theta/dt^2$, not $d^2 \tau/dt^2$.

Comment: Oh nevermind, ive been out of mathematics for a long time. The second derivative required the product rule i guess. My apologies, just getting back into mathematics

Comment: Is the $x$ another constant or a misused multiplication symbol? Note that in LaTeX/mathjax, you have $a\times b$ and $a\cdot b$, `$a\times b$ and $a\cdot b$`, available.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the problem appears partly to be a not clearly explained abuse of notation. The symbol $θ$ is used as coordinate, but implicitly also as symbol for two different functions. It might be clearer of one uses a longer formalism separating these roles with different symbols, using
$θ=f(t)$ for the original function and $θ=g(τ)=g(ωt)$ for the function depending on the modified time scale. Then for the derivatives you get
$$
\frac{dθ}{dt}=g'(τ)\frac{dτ}{dt}=g'(τ)ω\\
\frac{d^2θ}{dt^2}=g''(τ)\left(\frac{dτ}{dt}\right)^2+g'(τ)\frac{d^2τ}{dt^2}=g''(τ)ω^2\\
$$
The derivation prime denotes the derivative with respect to the function argument, whatever that is currently. And yes, $τ'(t)=$, $τ''(t)=0$, which is also used above.

Now one can also write in the $(τ,θ)$ dependency $g'(τ)=\frac{dθ}{dτ}$ and $g''(τ)=\frac{d^2θ}{dτ^2}$ to get back to the formulas that were originally in question.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get (dtau/dt)^2 term for the second derivative of theta?

Comment: The formula above contains a product. By the product rule of differentiation you get also a term where the second factor gets differentiated. As you noted, in this example the second derivative is zero, so this term is not present in the final result.

Comment: Oh for the derivative of g′(τ) with respect to t, the chain rule is used

Comment: Yes, that's how you get the square in the $τ'$ factor.